# Regression with Binary Outcome as Independent and Count as Dependent

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have data which is mental health posts, posted anonymously or with identity (1/0) revealed and then the dependent variables is the view count. Please could advise me what kind of regression would be appropriate for this type of problem?.

Answer (score 1):

What's most important is that you have the right model for the dependent variable.  In your case, the dependent variable is a [count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data).  That means you need a model for counts.  In some sense the default would be to use [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression), as the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) forms a kind of baseline for counts.  However, the Poisson distribution is very restrictive in assuming that the conditional variance has to equal the conditional mean.  Unfortunately, that isn't usually true.  A way to deal with that is to use negative binomial regression, and allow theta, the dispersion, to be a free parameter.  As a result, negative binomial regression is the default in practice.  You can find some tutorials for count regression on [UCLA's statistics help site](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/dae/).

Regarding the fact that the independent variable is yes/no, that's not a problem.  You can just use `1` and `0` for yes and no, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Its brilliant.

Comment: You're welcome, @JohnSmith.